# Why `2.0 - 1.1` and `2.0F - 1.1F` produce different results?

Tags: java, double, precision

I am working on a code where I am comparing `Double` and `float` values:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(2.0 - 1.1);            // 0.8999999999999999
        System.out.println(2.0 - 1.1 == 0.9);     // false

        System.out.println(2.0F - 1.1F);          // 0.9
        System.out.println(2.0F - 1.1F == 0.9F);  // true
        System.out.println(2.0F - 1.1F == 0.9);   // false
    }
}
```

Output is given below:

```
0.8999999999999999
false
0.9
true
false
```

---

I believe the `Double` value can save more precision than the `float`.

Please explain this, looks like the `float` value is not lose precision but the `double` one lose?

---

Edit:
@goodvibration I'm aware of that 0.9 can not be exactly saved in any computer language, i'm just confused how java works with this in detail, why `2.0F - 1.1F == 0.9F`, but `2.0 - 1.1 != 0.9`, another interesting found may help:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(2.0 - 0.9);            // 1.1
        System.out.println(2.0 - 0.9 == 1.1);     // true

        System.out.println(2.0F - 0.9F);          // 1.1
        System.out.println(2.0F - 0.9F == 1.1F);  // true
        System.out.println(2.0F - 0.9F == 1.1);   // false
    }
}
```

I know I can't count on the float or double precision, just.. can't  figure it out drive me crazy, whats the real deal behind this? Why `2.0 - 0.9 == 1.1` but `2.0 - 1.1 != 0.9` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `float` and `double`:

- [IEEE 754 single-precision binary floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)
- [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)

Let's run your numbers in a simple C program, in order to get their binary representations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    float val;
    struct {
        unsigned int fraction : 23;
        unsigned int exponent :  8;
        unsigned int sign     :  1;
    } bits;
} F;

typedef union {
    double val;
    struct {
        unsigned long long fraction : 52;
        unsigned long long exponent : 11;
        unsigned long long sign     :  1;
    } bits;
} D;

int main() {
    F f = {(float )(2.0 - 1.1)};
    D d = {(double)(2.0 - 1.1)};
    printf("%d %d %d\n"      , f.bits.sign, f.bits.exponent, f.bits.fraction);
    printf("%lld %lld %lld\n", d.bits.sign, d.bits.exponent, d.bits.fraction);
    return 0;
}
```

The printout of this code is:

```
0 126 6710886
0 1022 3602879701896396
```

Based on the two format specifications above, let's convert these numbers to rational values.

In order to achieve high accuracy, let's do this in a simple Python program:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext

getcontext().prec = 100

TWO = Decimal(2)

def convert(sign, exponent, fraction, e_len, f_len):
    return (-1) ** sign * TWO ** (exponent - 2 ** (e_len - 1) + 1) * (1 + fraction / TWO ** f_len)

def toFloat(sign, exponent, fraction):
    return convert(sign, exponent, fraction, 8, 23)

def toDouble(sign, exponent, fraction):
    return convert(sign, exponent, fraction, 11, 52)

f = toFloat(0, 126, 6710886)
d = toDouble(0, 1022, 3602879701896396)

print('{:.40f}'.format(f))
print('{:.40f}'.format(d))
```

The printout of this code is:

```
0.8999999761581420898437500000000000000000
0.8999999999999999111821580299874767661094
```

If we print these two values while specifying between 8 and 15 decimal digits, then we shall experience the same thing that you have observed (the `double` value printed as 0.9, while the `float` value printed as close to 0.9):

In other words, this code:

```
for n in range(8, 15 + 1):
    string = '{:.' + str(n) + 'f}';
    print(string.format(f))
    print(string.format(d))
```

Gives this printout:

```
0.89999998
0.90000000
0.899999976
0.900000000
0.8999999762
0.9000000000
0.89999997616
0.90000000000
0.899999976158
0.900000000000
0.8999999761581
0.9000000000000
0.89999997615814
0.90000000000000
0.899999976158142
0.900000000000000
```

Our conclusion is therefore that Java prints decimals with a precision of between 8 and 15 digits by default.

Nice question BTW...

Comment: Beautiful reasoning! But you have confuse what I observed, the snippet code result: (the `float` value printed as 0.9, while the `double` value printed as close to 0.9), what's that about.... XD

Comment: @hedleyyan: Right... well... maybe Java has different default settings for printing float values and for printing double values, which could explain your observation. In any case, regardless of your printouts, non of these values is exactly 0.9, as you can see in the 40-digit long printout that I wrote in my answer. And in fact, it is impossible to accurately represent any rational value whose denominator is not a power of 2 (for example, 73 / 16 can be represented accurately, while 16 / 73 cannot).

Comment: In my option, with no matter what settings, the double value is *equal or more accurate* than the float value, is that right? So in my case why float is *more accurate* ?

Comment: @hedleyyan: It is NOT. Look at the 40-digit printouts that I have provided in my answer! It just so happens that Java prints your values to a certain precision, thus making it look like the float value is exactly 0.9 (which it is NOT, as I've explained both in my answer and in the comment above yours).

Comment: I get your point, actually you had proven my point that the double value is more accurate than the float. ( `double: 0.8999999999999999111821580299874767661094` is more closer to 0.9 than `float: 0.8999999761581420898437500000000000000000`), but in output why other way around

Comment: @hedleyyan: Third (and last) time I'm going to try and explain this: When printing (in any language, not just in Java), we must limit the number of decimal digits printed, and decide what rounding-method to use for the last one. Each language/compiler/virtual machine/platform/envionment may choose different default values for this. For example, Java (or the JVM, I'm not entirely sure) can choose to use 7 decimal digits and round-to-nearest, in which case, `0.89999997` will be printed as `0.9`. That does not indicate better accuracy of the `float` value over the `double` value!!!

Comment: Thanks for your patience and sorry for my chatter...  follow your explain, then the problem is why double print `0.89999999..` not `0.9`, no matter what rounding cases, why `float` print 0.9 and `double` not?   again, sorry for my chatter.

Comment: @hedleyyan: I don't remember the exact syntax for specifying precision when printing decimals in Java, but I'm sure you can find it. Then, try to print your values in different precisions, and you'll get different printouts (for example, `0.9` for the `double` if you choose a very low precision, and `0.89999998` for the `float` if you choose a very high precision).

Answer (score 1):

Pop quiz: Represent 1/3rd, in decimal.

Answer: You can't; not precisely.

Computers count in binary. There are many more numbers that 'cannot be completely represented'. Just like, in the decimal question, if you have only a small piece of paper to write it on, you may simply go with `0.3333333` and call it a day, and you'd then have a number that is quite close to, but not entirely the same as, `1 / 3`, so do computers represent fractions.

Or, think about it this way: a float occupies 32-bits; a double occupies 64. There are only 2^32 (about 4 billion) different numbers that a 32-bit value can represent. And yet, even between 0 and 1 there are an infinite amount of numbers. So, given that there are at most 2^32 specific, concrete numbers that are 'representable precisely' as a float, any number that isn't in that blessed set of about 4 billion values, is not representable. Instead of just erroring out, you simply get the one in this pool of 4 billion values that IS representable, and is the closest number to the one you wanted.

In addition, because computers count in binary and not decimal, your sense of what is 'representable' and what isn't, is off. You may think that 1/3 is a big problem, but surely 1/10 is easy, right? That's simply `0.1` and that is a precise representation. Ah, but, a tenth works well in decimal. After all, decimal is based around the number 10, no surprise there. But in binary? a half, a fourth, an eighth, a sixteenth: Easy in binary. A tenth? That is as difficult as a third: **NOT REPRESENTABLE**.

0.9 is, itself, not a representable number. And yet, when you printed your float, that's what you got.

The reason is, printing floats/doubles is an art, more than a science. Given that only a few numbers are representable, and given that these numbers don't feel 'natural' to humans due to the binary v. decimal thing, you really need to add a 'rounding' strategy to the number or it'll look crazy (nobody wants to read 0.899999999999999999765). And that is precisely what System.out.println and co do.

But you really should take control of the rounding function: Never use System.out.println to print doubles and floats. Use `System.out.printf("%.6f", yourDouble);` instead, and in this case, BOTH would print `0.9`. Because whilst neither can actually represent 0.9 precisely, the number that is closest to it in floats (or rather, the number you get when you take the number closest to 2.0 (which is 2.0), and the number closest to 1.1 (which is not 1.1 precisely), subtract them, and then find the number closest to that result) – prints as 0.9 even though it isn't for floats, and does not print as 0.9 in double.